# Weka unable to read arff file

Tags: attributes, weka, arff

everyone..

I try to open an arff file using weka but the error appear as below:

**java.io.IOException: Unable to determine structure as arff (Reason: java.io.IOException: } expected at end of enumeration, read Token[EOL], line 6)**

This is part of the code to refer:

```
@RELATION AB_NYC_2019-2k

@ATTRIBUTE id numeric
@ATTRIBUTE host_id numeric
@ATTRIBUTE host_name {,Christopher+SamanthaAndMason,Dee,"Porfirio Firo & Maria","Robert Bob"}
@ATTRIBUTE neighbourhood_group {,Bronx,Brooklyn,"DeeDre & Mama Shelley",Manhattan,Queens,"Staten Island"}
@ATTRIBUTE neighbourhood {,Allerton,Arrochar,Arverne,Astoria,"Battery Park City","Bay Ridge",Bayside,Bedford-Stuyvesant}
@ATTRIBUTE latitude numeric
@ATTRIBUTE longitude numeric
@ATTRIBUTE room_type {"Entire home/apt","Private room","Shared room"}
@ATTRIBUTE price numeric
@ATTRIBUTE minimum_nights numeric
@ATTRIBUTE number_of_reviews numeric
@ATTRIBUTE last_review {,1/1/2013,1/1/2016,1/1/2017,1/1/2018,1/1/2019,1/10/2019}
@ATTRIBUTE reviews_per_month numeric
@ATTRIBUTE calculated_host_listings_count numeric
@ATTRIBUTE availability_365 numeric

@DATA
2539,2787,John,Brooklyn,Kensington,40.64749,-73.97237,Private room,149,1,9,10/19/2018,0.21,6,365
2595,2845,Jennifer,Manhattan,Midtown,40.75362,-73.98377,Entire home/apt,225,1,45,5/21/2019,0.38,2,355
3647,4632,Elisabeth,Manhattan,Harlem,40.80902,-73.9419,Private room,150,3,0,,,1,365
```

This is my [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AfUf6svAOkfczIXofwOrgEANxyTTPRMq/view?usp=sharing)

Can anyone help me? Thank you in advanced..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you generated the ARFF manually, introducing some errors:

- Weka uses `?` to denote missing values in the data section, not empty cells
- duplicate values in the nominal value lists are not allowed (`Dee` appears twice in `host_name`)

It is recommended to use the Java API for generating datasets instead of manually crafting ARFF text files.

Here is what I would do:

- change your dataset to a CSV file, by replacing the ARFF header (`@DATA` and above) with this CSV header row:

  ```
  id,host_id,host_name,neighbourhood_group,neighbourhood,latitude,longitude,room_type,price,minimum_nights,number_of_reviews,last_review,reviews_per_month,calculated_host_listings_count,availability_365
  ```
- install the [Common CSV Weka package](https://github.com/fracpete/common-csv-weka-package), as it handles CSV files better than Weka's native CSVLoader (and restart Weka for the package to be available)
- load the CSV using the `Common CSV` file format and check the `Invoke options dialog` check box before clicking on`OK`
- In the options dialog use the following custom options:

  - dateFormat: `M/d/yyyy`
  - dateRange: `12`
- Click `OK` to load it
- Apply the [StringToNominal](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/StringToNominal.html) filter to your dataset using `first-last` as range (default is `last`) to convert the string attributes into nominal ones.